# Searching fast in select from a varchar field

Tags: database, select, full-text-search, nvarchar

I have a database with thousands of records . Each record have a field named "_Text" that contains HTML Code obtained from a web page.

The field type is nvarchar(max).

My problem is searching a word in this table using 'Like' that take a long time to responed because the field have numerous words.

How I can make a fast searching within the '_text' field ??

Comment: Check if your RDBMS has support for some kind of [full text search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search). If it hasn't, you may have to build your own index of individual words from the records in your table to optimize single-word searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thousands of records does not seem like very much. Ideas:

1. You can create an index for the field where you intend to do the search
2. You can use fulltext search features
3. You can use tools, like nginx or elasticsearch
4. If you have a predefined set of words which might end up in your like parameter, then you can create a keywords field which will contain the keywords
5. Look at the query you generate. Is it optimal?

Comment: I dont use sqlserver , hence , I have to do it by code or designing a table.

Comment: Can you help me with more explanation or sample?

Comment: Not really you did not give us any details, you have just described the essence of the problem. I have replied with the essence of the solution. However, by searching on google you should be able to solve your problem from here.

Comment: Solution 1 and 4 may be my answer.

Comment: I don't have special problem. I used to search in DB using 'Like'%%' and it was very slow. Thank you for best replying .

Comment: If 4 is an option, then you should start with that. Indexing speeds up read operations, but slows down write operations. If you have a keywords field, it will drastically improve the performance of your search if you check your keywords instead of the larger value. If you have to check the larger value in case the value was not found in the keywords, then make sure you check the smaller keywords value first. If my answer was helpful, you can accept it so people in the future will be able to solve their problems using our conversation.